# Automatically attach VHD

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, vhd

Is it possible to attach vhd files automatically at Windows 7 startup? I'm imagine it will be like batch script or powershell script. I've tried [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/38899/windows-7-always-attach-vhd) solution before,but still wont work. Any guess guys?

Comment: what exactly is the problem with the solution from the referenced question?

Comment: I dont know where or when I have to execute it. any ideas?

Comment: The recommendation in the linked question was to create this script as .cmd file that gets included in the "StartUp" folder under your Start Menu.  Alternatively, you could register it as a "Run" item in the registry: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977(VS.85).aspx.

Comment: note that you must run the diskpart.cmd file "as administrator".

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely possible, you can even boot from a vhd. Scott Hanselman [blogged about it](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LessVirtualMoreMachineWindows7AndTheMagicOfBootToVHD.aspx) previously.

But I think the [solution from your linked question](https://serverfault.com/questions/38899/windows-7-always-attach-vhd/38915#38915) should do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with a CMD\ Bat command and Powershell. Both can be confusing for people. I made a very easy slim program to resolve this. Take a look at it and send me some feedback on it. The function is there to attach them in Windows 7, Vista and Server 2008. Hopefully in the next release they will set a function in the Console to allow it to attach at startup like a simple check box. This is really needed when you are BaremMetal booting or using a VHD as backup. you can download it and use it freely @ bmvhdloader.com "Love the VHD's"